# Jsoup вывод записей

Tags: android, jsoup

Подскажите как исправить вывод новостей в правильном порядке. Парсинг выводит данные: 1 - а, 1 - б,, 2 - а, 2 - б. А надо 1 - а, 2 - б.
Вот код:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    List<String> headersList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> contentList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView listview;
    List<Map<String, String>> data = new  
ArrayList <Map<String, String>>();

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    new SampleAsyncTask().execute();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
public class SampleAsyncTask extend
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            webRequest();
            //setUpSimpleAdapter();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        List<Map<String, String>> data = new 
ArrayList <Map<String, String>>();

        for(int i = 0; i < headersList.size(); i++){

            for(int j = 0; j < contentList.size(); j++){

            Map<String,String>oglas = new 
HashMap <String,String>();
            oglas.put("title", headersList.get(i));
            oglas.put("text", contentList.get(j));
            data.add(oglas);
            }
        }
        simpleAdapter = new 
 SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, data, 

 R.layout.list_item,
                                          new 
 String[]{"title","text"},
                                          new int[] 
 {R.id.titletext, R.id.fulltext});
        listview.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    }

}
public void webRequest() throws Exception{
    String servisURL = 
 "http://www.fcdynamo.kiev.ua/ru/allnews/";

    Document doc = 
 Jsoup.connect(servisURL).userAgent("Mozilla").get();

    Elements jobNode = doc.select("div[class=text- 
holder]");
    Elements headersNode = 
jobNode.select("div[class=text-holder] > h3");
    Elements contentNode = 
jobNode.select("div[class=text-holder] > p"); 

    for(int i = 0; i < headersNode.size(); i++){
        headersList.add(headersNode.get(i).text());
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < contentNode.size(); j++){
        contentList.add(contentNode.get(j).text());
    }

}
}
```